# How to install php 8 to aarch64 oracle linux?

Tags: yum, php, dnf, oracle-linux

Since [official Oracle Linux](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html) only support up to 7.4 and [Remi repo](https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=4016)  also doesn't support aarch64 , how to install PHP 8 to aarch64 oracle Linux?

Comment: See See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/214 aarch64 is now available for EL-9